# Meteor error with windows 8.1: your application has errors. waiting for file change

Tags: node.js, meteor

I am trying to create & rum meteor app on win 8.1 pc
what I done, I install meteor using official Meteor installer
I run following commands at desired path

```
meteor create myapp
```

this was ok
then `cd myapp`
this was also ok

but when I run command meteor to run the app, I got following result with error

```
[[[[[ ~\F\meteor\resolutions ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While loading plugin `compileTemplatesBatch` from packag
   module.js:338:15: Cannot find module
   '../modules/es6.object.get-own-property-descriptor'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dinesh
   Singh\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.7\pl
Batch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_mo
pt-runtime\node_modules\meteor-ecmascript-runtime\node_modu
t.js:12:1)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dinesh
   Singh\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.7\pl
Batch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_mo
pt-runtime\node_modules\meteor-ecmascript-runtime\server.js
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at npmRequire (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1665:14)
   at Module.useNode (packages/modules-runtime.js:453:20)
   at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:157:20)
   at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16)
   at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.ecmascript-runtime.
   (packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:24:18)
   at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:158:9)
   at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16)
   at packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:2832:15
   at packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:2845:3


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I search over the but didn't find specific result for windows.

Comment: Do you have `Node` and `npm` installed on your machine? if not , then try installing those.

Comment: yes, I installed node npm with node js official installer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on answers from this issue https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6609 you need to :

- Go to "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local.meteor\packages"
- Move the packages causing the issue to another folder as you won't be able to delete them on windows due to long file names (templating, templating-tools, ecmascript, standard-minifier-css)
- once the file deleted you can run "meteor npm install" then "meteor"

I have tested and it works for me.

Comment: @zied.abaoud I follow following (1)"C:\Users\username\AppData\Local.meteor\packages" move (templating, templating-tools, ecmascript, standard-minifier-css) to desktop(2)move to my desired location then 'meteor create myapp' then 'cd myapp' then run 'meteor', project was started at localhost:3000 , when I try in browser , default meteor app not working properly, when I click "click me" button counter increase but when page reload counter again start at 0 , I think it's not going right

Comment: Hi, this is because you haven't setup it yet to save the counter to a database, so its absolutely normal that it goes back to 0 when you refresh. Go ahead in the tutorial at the collections section and you will start inserting data to a mongo DB

Comment: thanks I am absolute new to node & meteor, can you provide exact reference link to setup db

Comment: Hi Dinesh, as said before you should follow the meteor tutorial, on the collections section https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections  you will learn how to setup the database. You should also accept one of the answers since they answer the main topic question to help the other users.

Answer (score 4):

As the latest version got this problem, use previous version to create a sample app like this,

```
meteor create --release 1.2.1 test-app
cd test-app
meteor
```

found on : https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6609

Comment: thanks for help, these commands started the app at localhost:3000 but not properly , eg- when I clicks the button it increase  the button click count but when page page reload counter again start at 0

Comment: Temporary solution is available at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36309009/meteor-app-crashing-when-i-run-it-on-cmd

Answer (score 0):

I just removed all packages (withaout meteor) from AppData\Local.meteor\packages and run my app again. Meteor downloaded all packeges and now it is working.

Answer (score 0):

The following fix worked for me:

Uninstall meteor from Windows (Programs and Features).
Install meteor (https://www.meteor.com/install)
Create a new Project (https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app)