# meteor app crashing when I run it on cmd

Tags: meteor

I am new to meteor please help. I created my first app but when I try to run it so that I can view it on the browser I get the following error message:

```
C:\projects\myapp>meteor
[[[[[ C:\projects\myapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While loading plugin `compileTemplatesBatch` from package `templating`:
   module.js:338:15: Cannot find module '../modules/es6.object.get-own-property-descriptor'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.7\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor-ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\core-js\es6\object.js:12:1)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
   (C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\templating\1.1.7\plugin.compileTemplatesBatch.os\npm\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor\ecmascript-runtime\node_modules\meteor-ecmascript-runtime\server.js:1:1)
   at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
   at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at npmRequire (C:\tools\isobuild\bundler.js:1665:14)
   at Module.useNode (packages/modules-runtime.js:453:20)
   at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:157:20)
   at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16)
   at meteorInstall.node_modules.meteor.ecmascript-runtime.runtime.js (packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:24:18)
   at fileEvaluate (packages/modules-runtime.js:158:9)
   at require (packages/modules-runtime.js:92:16)
   at packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:2832:15
   at packages/ecmascript-runtime.js:2845:3


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

I haven't edited the default application that's created when you create an application in cmd. I simply followed tutorial instructions on how to run a created app so that you view it on the browser.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This issue popped up from the recent 1.3 release on Windows platform. By the way, community has already found a workaround. Following the steps described in [this issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6609) by @adanlozano you should resolve the error:

1. Navigate to `C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages`
   and delete the issue package folders entirely (`templating`, `templating-tools`, `ecmascript`, `standard-minifier-css`)
2. Run your terminal window as Administrator to ensure no issues remaining in the project directory where your App is located.
3. Run `meteor` and wait patiently as it attempts to download the missing packages, this might take a while.

Answer (score 1):

For future visitors, this issue has been fixed in Meteor 1.3.1. See ramijarrar's comment on the relevant [Github issue](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6609).