# new meteor install on windows 10 cannot find module

Tags: meteor

I have a fresh install of meteor on windows 10 I have tried to follow the simple-todos tutorial but fall over at the first attempt to run.
The following is the first part of the error trace:
*

```
[[[[[ C:\simpletodos ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Errors prevented startup:
   While loading plugin `compileTemplatesBatch` from package `templating`:
   module.js:338:15: Cannot find module
 '../modules/es6.object.get-own-property-descriptor'
   at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
   at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
   at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
   at require (module.js:380:17)
   at Object.<anonymous>
```

*
Anybody got any ideas what to do?

Answer (score 0):

the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300388/meteor-error-with-windows-8-1-your-application-has-errors-waiting-for-file-cha) works for windows 10 too.

the answer references this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/36304697/4235925